# Adding a header slot to customize header color in data table in vuetify 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify 2 to create a data table for an app.  In the data table I have custom headers, with slots, including "text", "value", "sortable". Is there a slot I can add to specify the font color and font size I want for each header? If I add a class parameter, how do I add the CSS specifics needed for the headers?

Example code I am using:

```
 data: () => ({
    dataFilters: {},
    selectedRows: [],
    gridConfig: {
      records: [],
      loading: true,
      options: {
        itemsPerPageOptions: [10, 25, 50, 100],
        totalPages: 0,
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        page: 1,
        descending: false,
      },
      headers: [
        {
          text: '__HEADER__MENU__',
          value: `__HEADER__MENU__`,
          sortable: false,
        },
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible to set custom color to vuetify data-table header and font size

> You need to use class property in headers object

```
headers: [
        {
          text: '__HEADER__MENU__',
          value: `__HEADER__MENU__`,
          sortable: false,
          class: "success--text title"
        },
```

success--text class changes the color of your header
title increase the font size of you header, read all the fonts typography and colors in Vuetify

For dynamically setting the headers classes, use created hook to loop through this.headers and set the headers

> Here is the working codepen:
>   https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/WNNGzwm?&editable=true&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
          class: 'success--text title',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: yes, this helps a lot! But how can I edit the CSS of "success--text tile"? Can I just make changes in the style sheet related to success--text tile? Or is there something else I need to do? For example, I need the font to be blue.

Comment: succes--text and title are the predefined styles in vuetify, you can read about this here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/typography    https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors, you can also  add custom css and add those classes here , it will work fine